# Read and Write to Windows pipes in separate threads

Tags: c++, windows

In my program I start the thread to redirect output to console:

```
  while(TRUE)
  {
     if (!ReadFile(hPipeRead,lpBuffer,sizeof(lpBuffer),
                                      &nBytesRead,NULL) || !nBytesRead)
     {
        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE)
           break; // pipe done - normal exit path.
        else
           DisplayError("ReadFile"); // Something bad happened.
     }

     // Display the character read on the screen.
     if (!WriteConsole(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),lpBuffer,
                       nBytesRead,&nCharsWritten,NULL))
        DisplayError("WriteConsole");
  }
```

The problem is that it is a loop. Is it possible to to avoid the run of the loop by making the thread to wait until something appears in the pipe?

The problem becomes more intense when there is an analogous thread for writing.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You're pipe doesn't look to be in async mode, so it should be blocking until data is ready or the pipe is closed. And since you already said this is running on a separate thread, I'm not quite sure I see what the problem is.

Comment: What's at the other end of the pipe?